# Changing position of buttons in slider module (yoocarousel) in joomla

Tags: php, javascript, css, joomla

I installed a YooCarousel module (Slider) in one of my articles in Joomla.
However, I can't seem to change the location of the Prev and Next button.

I've tried checking out the YooTheme website under their help/documentation section for YooCarousel, but it only shows how to setup the module, not change button position.

I've also tried change the CSS, but it doesn't seem to work for some weird reason.

Here's a link to my page:
http://prodigypublicrelations.com/index.php?option=com_content&id=17

Answer (score 0):

You can change them by changing the CSS associated with the `button-next` class.

However, the clickable target to go next is much larger than the button.